# NullReferenceException in DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.KeyGenerator.GenerateKey

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, donut-caching

I'm having the problem described by @Aviv in this post:
http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3#125

I looked for the error here and on [Codeplex](http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) but not found.

**The environment is Medium Trust!**

## Route

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "LetsGo.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

## Controller

```
[DonutOutputCache(CacheProfile = "StaticPage")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
        return View(_themeParty.Repository.Query().Published(true).ToList());
}

[ChildActionOnly]
[DonutOutputCache(CacheProfile = "DataCache")]
public PartialViewResult Subsidiaries() { return PartialView(_subsidiaries.Repository.Query().Published().ToList()); }
```

## Web.config

```
<caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="DataCache" enabled="true" duration="10800" varyByParam="*" />
        <add name="StaticPage" enabled="true" duration="21600" varyByParam="*" />
        <add name="ByHeader" enabled="true" duration="300" varyByHeader="*" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

## _Layout.cshtml

```
...
 @Html.Action("Subsidiaries", "Home", new { area = "" })
...
```

## Full error

```
Server Error in '/LetsGo' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.KeyGenerator.GenerateKey(ControllerContext context, CacheSettings cacheSettings) +777
   DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.DonutOutputCacheAttribute.ExecuteCallback(ControllerContext context, Boolean hasErrors) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception) +168
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +652
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +161
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +304
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +461
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +370

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Comment: Hi @Riderman, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a bug in for this:

http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/workitem/2533